# Passing argument from controller to controller not working

Tags: php, redirect, controller, laravel-5, arguments

Aloha, I'm making a workout manager in which you have a dashboard displaying  your 5 last workouts. I have set a form for each one workout for allowing the user to delete any of them. Here the **form** in the **dashboard**:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['dashboard.workout.destroy', $workout->id], 'style' =>'display:inline-block;', 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
```

This route will call this method in **WorkoutController.php**

```
public function destroy($id, Request $request)
{
    $workout = Workout::findOrFail($id);
    $workout->delete();
    $message = "Workout deleted successfully!";

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index', ['message' => $message]);
}
```

And this route will call this method in **DashboardController.php**

```
public function index($message = null)
{
  $user = Auth::user();

  // Workouts
  ...

  // Inbodies
  ...

  // Measures
  ...

  return view('dashboard.index', compact('user','workoutsDesc','workouts','lastInbody','inbodies','measures','lastMeasure','message'));
}
```

The question is that I'm trying to pass the variable $message from **WorkoutController** to **DashboardController** for displaying a successfull alert after deleting a workout, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried with:

```
return redirect()->action('Dashboard\DashboardController@index', [$message]); 

return redirect()->action('Dashboard\DashboardController@index')->with('message', $message);

return redirect()->route('dashboard.index', $message);
```

But I still trying to find the way for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from [Laravel 5.1 Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects):

`If your route has parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the route method`

As the message is not a parameter to your route, so you can't pass that. A possible solution can be [Flashing data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data). Check the next controller if the session has that key and contain a value, then add it to a variable and pass to the view. 

Hope this works.